# Updating JHipster from 2.2x to 3.4 and structure of JS controllers caused issues

Tags: angularjs, controller, jhipster

I have a project started with JHipster last winter. I recently updated to the latest version (3.4). According to the documentation, JHipster should still create entities and everything using the JHipster version of the project, unless I misunderstood something. But the JS controllers it creates are different, and the newly created files aren't working/compiling:

- `<jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>` is not recognized (directive wasn't present)
- `public static HttpHeaders createFailureAlert(String entityName, String errorKey, String defaultMessage)` was used in the Java files, but not present in the HeaderUtil

and so on.

Updating all the entities is not an option, because there's a lot of custom code in there. Probably every single project other than a sample one does more than simple CRUD.

As a side question, why did the structure of the JS controllers change ? I am relatively new to AngularJS, and I am just trying to understand why this changed and what are the benefits of the new structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no upgrade path from JHipster 2.x to JHipster 3.x.

The structure of the JavaScript was changed from 2.x to 3.x to conform to the John Papa Angular Style Guide, located [here.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)